# Django. How to get related_name of a field from the contenttypes framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

How can I retrieve a related_name of a known field using content types framework?

I have reached as far as getting the actual field. But I have no idea how to lay hands on it's arguments.

```
field = content_type.model_class()._meta.get_field_by_name('field_name')
related_name = ?
```

Comment: Can you post relevant model definition please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, got it. As a reminder, `field_name` is what I know, it's hardcoded.

```
related_name = content_type.model_class().field_name.field.related_query_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks gwaramadze! Here is a similar answer if you have an object:

```
object._meta.get_field(field_name).related_query_name()
```